# SQL - Doctrine / DQL how do I build this query

Tags: sql, doctrine, many-to-many

I have and entity called `Event` and one called `Employee`

`Event` has a `ManyToOne` with `Employee` called `scheduledEmployee`

It also has a `ManyToMany` with `Employee` called `employeeRequests`

There is a `column` in the `Event table` called `employee_id`

There is also a `Join Table` called `Event_Employee_Requests`

How would I go about querying for all `Events` that an `Employee` has been scheduled OR requested?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.scheduledEmployee = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery();
```

I am able to get All `Events` that are scheduled but am unsure how to get the requested events as well.

## Update

I have tried the following:

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->join('e.employeeRequests', 'r')
        ->where('e.scheduledEmployee = :user')
        ->orWhere('(r.id = :user AND e.scheduledEmployee is NULL)')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery();
```

This give the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM event e0_ JOIN event_user_request e2_ ON e0_.id = e2_.event_id INNER JOIN fos_user f1_ ON f1_.id = e2_.user_id WHERE e0_.scheduled_employee_id = 5 OR ((f1_.id = 5 AND e0_.scheduled_employee_id IS NULL))
```

This query works if I remove the `ON` clause for the `JOIN event_user_request`, though I'm not sure how to do that with DQL.

Currently the above `SQL` returns only requested events and not the ones that are scheduled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get events which are scheduled/ requested for an employee you can go with left join approach which is similar to your query builder code

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
->leftJoin('e.employeeRequests', 'r')
->where('e.scheduledEmployee = :user')
->orWhere('(r.id = :user AND e.scheduledEmployee IS NULL)')
->setParameter('user', $user)
->getQuery();
```

In sql it would look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM event e0_ 
LEFT JOIN event_user_request e2_ ON e0_.id = e2_.event_id 
LEFT JOIN fos_user f1_ ON f1_.id = e2_.user_id 
WHERE e0_.scheduled_employee_id = 5 
OR (f1_.id = 5 AND e0_.scheduled_employee_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: That seems to work! What is the difference between `Join` and `leftJoin`?

Comment: This is best explanation  i guess [What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)